# Why isProtectedDataAvailable is not true inside applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, data-protection

Getting `isProtectedDataAvailable` true even inside `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` delegate in `AppDelegate.m` (sometimes). As per documentation `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` is called when protected data is unavailable so **why I am getting it `true`?**

```
- (void) applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:(UIApplication *)application {
    DDLogVerbose(TAG, "%d", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable]);
}
```

---

<sup>**isProtectedDataAvailable** - The value of this property is false if data protection is enabled and the device is currently locked. The value of this property is set to true if the device is unlocked or if content protection is not enabled. When the value of this property is false, files that were assigned the complete or completeUnlessOpen protection key cannot be read or written by your app. The user must unlock the device before your app can access them.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per documentation `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` is called when protected data is unavailable

Not quite. From the [docs for `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623019-applicationprotecteddatawillbeco?language=objc):

> Tells the delegate that the protected files **are about to become unavailable.**

This method is posted shortly *before* the protected files become unavailable, meaning they are still available during the call to this method.

Comment: Then at what point of time I can be confirmed that the protected data is unavailable? I mean `isProtectedDataAvailable` is false? Is there any certain way to get so? If no, any workaround?

Comment: From what I can see, it doesn't look like Apple provides a way to know the _exact_ time it becomes unavailable. Apple's thinking is that your app should just assume that right after this call the data is unavailable.

Comment: Apples thinking is ok on security perspective for `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` but when we consider same grace period for `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeAvailable` it creates problem to developer. How long my app should wait to get confirmed that now data is available to access. Just by assuming? :(

Comment: There is no such thing as `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeAvailable`. There is a `applicationProtectedData **Did** BecomeAvailable` ([docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623044-applicationprotecteddatadidbecom?language=objc)), which is called when the data _is_ available, so you are free to access it during that method.

Comment: Ohh, your are right. Sorry for my mistake. Now it makes sense,